# How to drag and drop a LibGDX Image actor

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, libgdx

I have a LibGDX scene with a couple of Images (the Actor subclass). I want to drag one Image and drop it on another. I started with the source code located at [DragDropTest.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/DragAndDropTest.java). Since I basically want the source to be the payload I've tried modifying `payload.setDragActor` to use the source Image. It kind of works, I need to add the code to place the payload actor back in the stage but that isn't my issue.

My problem that that the payload (when it's the source actor or a separate actor) doesn't really get dragged. Instead what happens is the payload actor positions itself slightly down and to the right of the mouse cursor. I want to place the payload, not point to where I want the payload placed. It doesn't feel like dragging at all, it feels like something is following the cursor. I see the same behavior on the Android emulator as I do on the desktop version of the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went digging through the LibGDX source for `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.DragAndDrop` and found the answer. The code places the payload +14 in the X direction from the cursor and (-20 - payLoadActor.getHeight()) in the Y direction which is why I'm not able to visually drag the payload. There is a `setDragActorPosition` method that can be used to correct the position. If you always want the dragged payload to be centered under the cursor you can do:

```
final DragAndDrop dragAndDrop = new DragAndDrop();
dragAndDrop.setDragActorPosition(-(sourceImage.getWidth()/2), sourceImage.getHeight()/2);
```

If you want the dragged payload to maintain its placement under the cursor/finger than you have to use the cursor position when calling `setDragActorPosition` in the `dragStart` method.

```
final DragAndDrop dragAndDrop = new DragAndDrop();
dragAndDrop.addSource(new DragAndDrop.Source(sourceImage) {
    public DragAndDrop.Payload dragStart (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        DragAndDrop.Payload payload = new DragAndDrop.Payload();
        payload.setDragActor(sourceImage);
        dragAndDrop.setDragActorPosition(-x, -y + sourceImage.getHeight());
        return payload;
    }
    public void dragStop (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Target target) {
        sourceImage.setBounds(50, 125, sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight());
        if(target != null) {
            sourceImage.setPosition(target.getActor().getX(), target.getActor().getY());
        }
        virtualStage.addActor(sourceImage);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that there is a little bug - minus sign is on the x argument. It should be on the y argument: "dragAndDrop.setDragActorPosition( sourceImage.getWidth()/2, -(sourceImage.getHeight()/2) )"

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing any code, so it's hard to know what you are actually doing. Based on your description, it sounds like you are placing the payload at where the cursor is rather than moving it the same offset as the cursor moved since you started dragging.

Assuming you're using an ActorGestureListener, this is what I do in my app.

```
float touchX, touchY;

public void touchDown(InputEvent ev, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    touchX = x;
    touchY = y;
    ...
}

public void pan(InputEvent ev, float x, float y, float dx, float dy) {
    moveBy(x - touchX, y - touchY);
    ...
}
```

This way you are moving your actor by the same amount as the mouse cursor moved, so it's like the pointer "glued" itself to whereever you touched your actor. Also, I believe the events in libgdx makes it so that you will not receive the pan events until the cursor has moved a bit inside your actor, so be aware of that when testing (moving the cursor a few pixels only will not trigger the pan events).

Comment: As I said the code I'm using is https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/DragAndDropTest.java
I'm not placing anything, `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.DragAndDrop` should handle this for me from what I understand but the position is gives the actor (payload) as the cursor moves seems stupid and doesn't visually correspond to dragging.

Comment: And I see why you missed the source code I linked to that I was using - someone edited my link down to the class name and made it easy to miss.