# Libgdx actor rotation drag position

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can I set the drag position of a rotated libGDX actor?

For an non rotated actor, the normal drag position is at the center. In order to set the drag position where the finger is touched, I use the following method as described here:
[How to drag and drop a LibGDX Image actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062429/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-libgdx-image-actor)

`dragAndDrop.setDragActorPosition(-x, -y + sourceImage.getHeight())`

This works flawlessly only when the actor is not rotated. Now if I rotate the actor using either of the below options:

Option 1: `rotateBy(-90)`
Option 2: `addAction(Actions.rotateBy(-90))`

the drag position is no longer under my finger because the coordinates are rotated. I tried using `localToParentCoordinates()` provided by the Actor class and rotation matrix algorithm but both doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Container.

```
Container<Actor> container = new Container<>(myRotatedActor);
```

Apply all your drag & drop logic to the container.

When you want to rotate, apply the rotation to the child (myRotatedActor) within the Container.